# How to integrate Kommunicate into ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, kommunicate

I am new to ASP.Net and I want to integrate Kommunicate into a website. Do I only add the javascript code (for the Kommunicate chatbot) between the <body> tags in the _Layout.cshtml?

Or there is more that i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to use the installation script provided by Kommunicate. Here is how to get the installation script: https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/web-installation#web-installation

Once you added the script and chatbot does not appear. Please restart the server once.